# Dropdown menu Overlay

Tags: javascript

I have issue with menu dropdown, hope anyone can help.
https://www.zzpstart.nl/

When I click 'menu' to open dropdown all work fine ( I get overlay in background and menu opened ) and if I click 'menu' to close still all fine ( menu and overlay closed ) BUT if I click outside of dropdown menu I get dropdown closed which is fine but still overlay active pff.

here is script Im using:

```
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    $('.drop-btn').on('click', function(e) { 

        if ($(this).hasClass("uk-open")) {
            $("body").addClass('drop');
            $(".overlay").addClass('active');
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass('drop');
            $(".overlay").removeClass('active');
        }
   })
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you add the script you use chen you click outside the dropdown menu ? It seems class `drop` is not removed from body neither class `active` from `<div id="overlay"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually unnecessary to check state. Just toggle the relevant classes.

```
$('.drop-btn, .overlay').click(function() { 
    $('body').toggleClass('drop');
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Note that I've added the mask class to the click selector as well.

Protip: Single quotes for JS, double for HTML. Save yourself some debugging and escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#overlay")[0]){
    console.log('the menu is open');
    $(".overlay").removeClass('active');
    $("body").removeClass('drop');
} else {
    console.log('the menu is not open');
}
```

What is happened is the classses are not being removed because they are set when you click but you haven't put in logic to remove them on focusout

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answser with only this piece of code and a only from the inspector. However, it seems you are not adding any onclick event when you  click outside the dropdown menu. You can consider using this :

```
$('#overlay').on('click', function(e) { 
    $('body').toggleClass('drop');
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

This code will remove your overlay if you click on it. However, because you added a z-index on header, making going above the overlay, clicking on the header will not remove the overlay. You should consider either making your full overlay covering header or make twi div inside, one transparent, ont dark because you can't use selector `$('#overlay, , .tm-header')` since your menu button is inside your header. You could also consider using a selector like `$(':not(.uk-dropdown)')` but can't be sure about the result.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for helping me with this! 
I tried all suggestions and all work :) but I tooked @isherwood as it's really simple.

Now when I have real experts on same page :) I have to ask one more question about second part of that menu.

Inside of Dropdown I have tabs menu made out of Wordpress parent / children pages.. so, Im calling there sidebar (widget Pages) to display all pages and then I added script to make that works as Tabs menu..

```
$('#pages-2 > ul > li.page_item_has_children').on('click', function (event) { 
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('ul > li.page_item_has_children ul.children').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
$('#pages-2 > ul > li.page_item_has_children:first').trigger('click');
```

so with that script I got parent link on click to display ul with children pages.

And this is working just great for what I need BUT (as always) 
I have another issue 
- I have to display parent link somehow inside ul.children because I need link to parent page too.. or even more > plus parent page title.

Does anyone have any suggestion :)

And THANK YOU ALL ONE MORE TIME!